# How to add a field to multipart/form-data before forwarding to another server?

Tags: node.js, typescript, http, next.js

I'm trying to upload a pdf to a NextJS endpoint, add a userId field to the form-data before forwarding it to another server for file storage. How would I do this?

I can forward the request fairly easily as i have done below, but I can't figure out how to add a field before forwarding:

```
const createResource = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method != "POST") res.status(405).send("Not allowed");

  const session = await getServerSession(req, res, nextAuthOptions);
  if (!session || !session.user) {
    res.status(403).send({
      content: "You need to login to access this route.",
    });
    return;
  }
  const uploadRes = await fetch("http://107.155.121.13:8080/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": req.headers["content-type"] ?? "",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.FILE_TOKEN,
    },
    body: req.body,
  });

  if (!uploadRes.ok) throw new Error("It doesn't work");
  res.send("ok");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to the `body` param in `options` for `fetch`.

Like:

```
const params = {
    userId: value,
    ...req.body
};

const uploadRes = await fetch("http://107.155.121.13:8080/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    body: params,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": req.headers["content-type"] ?? "",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + process.env.FILE_TOKEN,
    },
  });
```

Comment: Since this is a multipart/form-data type the body isn't a simple object type, it's encoded for the request which is why i'm having difficulties

Comment: try this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36153#discussioncomment-3029675